# Tracebacks SSL Error and Item Not Clickable with Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I need a way to handle an SSL Cert Error within My Code:
This is the traceback:

```
[29756:38612:0402/135226.106:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -208
[29756:38612:0402/135226.112:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -208
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\remove_sec_groups_inactive_users.py", line 104, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Right now I am able to get by this but would like to capture the SSL errors on the page due to no SSL certificate. Furthermore, another issue is arrising with messages referring to a handshake failure for TCP:

```py
PS C:\Users\richard.barrett\Git\ITDataServicesInfra\Python\Skyward\Reports> [6228:20372:0403/143125.317:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -208
[6228:20372:0403/143355.329:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -208
```

These are are all for the most part Items I need to Capture and offer a warning  message v. clutter my screen.

I am also having another traceback where a particular item is not clickable. I am trying to click on the download export by clicking on a button that looks like this:
[image]

The traceback is:

```
  File ".\export_secured_users_list_report.py", line 161, in <module>
    element.click();
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a id="browsetool_export" class="toolLink openText" alt="Export Options" tooltip="Export Options" tooltip-position="top" onmouseout="getMenu('export',this).hide();" onmouseover="getMenu('export',this).keepOpen();" href="javascript:getMenu('export',this).toggle()" onclickx="fwSky.browse.exportExcel();" aria-labelledby="" style="">...</a> is not clickable at point (897, 140). Other element would receive the click: <div id="lockDiv" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 684px; width: 100%; visibility: visible; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0;" oncontextmenu="return false;"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.163)
```

Here is my code:
https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITDataServicesInfra/blob/master/Python/Skyward/Reports/export_secured_users_list_report.py

```py
#!/bin/usr/env python
# ===========================================================
# Created By: Richard Barrett
# Organization: DVISD
# DepartmenT: Data Services
# Purpose: Skyward Reports
# Date: 04/03/2020
# ===========================================================
import selenium
import shutil
import xlsxwriter
import os
import unittest
import requests
import subprocess
import getpass
import platform
import socket
import ssl
import pynput
import logging
import time 
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from datetime import date

decrypt = "gpg --output secrets.json --decrypt secrets.gpg" 

if os.path.exists("secrets.gpg"):
      returned_value = subprocess.call(decrypt, shell=True)
else:
        print("The file does not exist!")
        print("You should probably create a secret!")
        print("gpg --output filename.gpg --encrypt filename.json")

import json
with open('secrets.json','r') as f:
      config = json.load(f)

# Definitions
# find_elements_by_name
# find_elements_by_xpath
# find_elements_by_link_text
# find_elements_by_partial_link_text
# find_elements_by_tag_name
# find_elements_by_class_name
# find_elements_by_css_selector

# System Variables
today = date.today()
date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
node = platform.node()
system = platform.system()
username = getpass.getuser()
version = platform.version()
keyboard = Controller()

# Upload Path Variables 
file_input_inactive_users = os.path.abspath("<insert_file_path>")

# URL Variables 
login_url = ''
redirect_url = ''
reports_scheduler_url = ''
custom_reports_url = ''

# Check for Version of Chrome

# WebDriver Path for OS.System
if platform.system() == ('Windows'):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
elif platform.system() == ('Linux'):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/rbarrett/Drivers/Google/Chrome/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
elif platform.system() == ('Darwin'):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='~/Drivers/Google/Chrome/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver')
else:
    print("Are you sure you have the Selenium Webdriver installed in the correct path?")

# TearDown Method
def tearDown(self):
    self.browser.close()

# ShutDown Method 
def shutDown(self):
    self.browser.quit()

# Parent URL
#browser.get(config['URL']['target_url'])
#browser.get("https://skyward-student.del-valle.k12.tx.us/scripts/wsisa.dll/WService=wsEAplus/seplog01.w?nopopup=true")
#options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors")
browser.get("https://skyward-dev.del-valle.k12.tx.us/scripts/wsisa.dll/WService=wsEAplusTrn/seplog01.w?nopopup=true")
time.sleep(5)

# Click on Advanced Button for Certificate Error
# XPATH //*[@id='details-button']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='details-button']")))
element.click();

# Click on Proceed
# XPATH //*[@id'proceed-link']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "proceed-link")))
element.click();
time.sleep(10)

# Credentials NEEDS UNIT TEST
username = browser.find_element_by_id("login")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
username.send_keys(config['user']['name'])
password.send_keys(config['user']['password'])

# Authentication submit.click()
# For XPATH = //*[@id='bLogin']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='bLogin']")))
element.click();
print("Logging into Skyward!")
print("Authenticated")

# Click and Span Skyward Contact Access
# Adminsitration XPATH = //*[@id='nav_ContactAccess']/span
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='nav_ContactAccess']/span")))
element.click();

# Click on Secured Users Access
# Adminsitration XPATH = //*[@id='nav_SecuredUserSuperUser']/span
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='nav_SecuredUserSuperUser']/span")))
element.click();

# Click on id="browsetool_export"
# Opens Options to Download Report
# XPATH = //*[@id='browsetool_export']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='browsetool_export']")))
element.click();

# Click on .CSV Radio Button
# XPATH = //*[@id='ExCOptCSV']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ExCOptCSV']")))
element.click();

# Click on Export Button
# XPATH = //*[@id='bExport']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='bExport']")))
element.click();

# Click on id="browsetool_export"
# Opens Options to Download Report
# XPATH = //*[@id='browsetool_export']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='browsetool_export']")))
element.click();

# Click on .xlsx Radio Button
# XPATH = //*[@id='ExCOptXLSX']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ExCOptXLSX']")))
element.click();

# Click on Export Button 
# XPATH  = //*[@id='bExport']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='bExport']")))
element.click();
time.sleep(20)

# Click on Download Export Button
# XPATH = //*[@id='printMsgBtn1']
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='printMsgBtn1']")))
element.click();

# Click on Run Button 
# Run Button XPATH = 
# Delete Unencrypted JSON File
if os.path.exists("secrets.json"):
  os.remove("secrets.json")
  print("The file was removed and everything is clean!")
else:
  print("The file does not exist")


# Close Browser Session Gracefully              
print("The Export was successfull!")
#browser.quit()
```

Comment: Okay so I found out what the issue was, but am still getting an error as I have to wait on another element to become available as it processes the file, once the file has been processed it can ben downloaded. Furthermore, I was missing a download step after the export step for the .csv file.

Comment: I am going to open another question up in the hopes that I can get some answers.